# retrieve people on same flight

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve all people  on same flight.

Db Model looks like:

```
Airplane(airplane_id),airplane_name,modelno)
Passenger (id,firstname,lastname,...)
Booking(booking_id,passenger_id,destination_id,flight_date,....)
Destinations(id,airplane_id,route,distance)
```

What do i need to correct in this query

```sql
SELECT * FROM Passenger as P
left join Booking as B 
on P.id = B.passenger_id
left join Destinations as D 
on D.id = B.destination_id
left join Airplane as A 
on A.airplane_id = D.airplane_id;
```

How will i use where statement??

Comment: What's wrong with the query actually? Share us please with what data do you have and what result are trying to achieve

Comment: Hey,I dont have the db prepared ..i am only writing everything.thts why i am not able to check whats result after running this

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are joining on all the wrong Ids. See below for what they should be based on your column names. (If this is incorrect I would highly recommend changing your column names so they are less confusing). I have also included a sample where clause, you can put any condition you like in there though.

```
SELECT P.*
FROM
    Passenger AS P
    JOIN Booking AS B ON P.Id = B.Passenger_Id
    JOIN Destinations AS D ON D.Id = B.Destination_Id
    JOIN Airplane AS A ON A.Airplane_Id = D.Airplane_Id
WHERE
    D.flight_date = '3/16/2021'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can execute this query, then add a where clause to filter the results

```
SELECT * 
FROM Airplane a
inner join Booking b on b.airplane_id = a.airplane_id
inner join Passenger p on p.id = b.passenger_id
inner join Destination d on d.id = b.destination_id
```